# Unable to load jdbc driver eclipse

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I get the following error while trying to load MySQL Driver:

```
  java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
      at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
      at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
      at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
      at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
      at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
      at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:171)
      at amazon.category.database.MerchantAdoptionStats.main(MerchantAdoptionStats.java:96)
```

Th relevant code is:

```
try {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");   //line 96
    //Some more code
} catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

I am using eclipse and here are the settings(please see the added jar in `classpath`):

[image]

What else am I missing?

EDIT:
Run time configrations:

[image]

Comment: That's java build path. Is it same as runtime class path ? Do check.

Comment: @AmitSharma how to check.I do not know much in eclipse

Comment: build path != runtime path.  Like Amit said, make sure the jar is available at runtime.

Comment: @AmanDeepGautam The runtime classpath location depends on how you are launching the JVM.  Is this a standalone app, web app or something else?  Include those details in your question.

Comment: @MadConan Can't he mark the Jar for export?

Comment: @KevinBowersox Yes, but that has been hit or miss for me.  I'm used to explicitly defining it in the runtime path.

Comment: @AmitSharma after commenting I did that(jsut I asked casully). Sadly it is there

Comment: @AmanDeepGautam Try going to over one tab to the order and export tab to make sure the jar is marked for export.  Then do a clean `Alt` + `P`, `N`

Comment: Are you using the exact bit version of connector jar ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have included mysql jdbc drivers in build path of your project, which is not same as runtime path.

Check your runtime classpath by going to `Run -> Run Configurations` and select your application configuration. Check the classpath setting there.

Comment: some sanity checks: Do you have read access to /usr/local/include/....jar? Unzip the jar file and make sure it contains the class file.

Comment: Could you please print the exception you are getting **now** after the runtime is configured? I can see the IDE complaining that you have not mentioned a class with main(...).

Comment: it was already configured. I did not change anything. Yes I have sudo access.

Comment: running eclipse as sudo? Does eclipse process have read access to that file?

Comment: Yes. Anyway, I restarted it and now it is working. Do not know why. Many thanks for help.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42676/discussion-between-amit-sharma-and-aman-deep-gautam)

Comment: Sorry after so much hustle yesterday I just switched off the system.

Comment: It is accepted as an answer because I think that this thread discusses whatever can possibly go wrong while loading the java driver for connection.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you try these two steps:

1. Connect updated mysql jar in buildpath.
2. try to change `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` to `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver`.

I faced the same problem but when I change my mysql driver then my application was running fine.